# How do I migrate from XAMPP to WAMP?

Tags: xampp, migration, wamp, wampserver, database-migration

I am currently working on XAMPP 1.7.4 and I want to migrate to latest WAMP server for PHP 7. Is it possible to migrate all my projects and database? If yes, then how should I do it?

Comment: Try one sample PHP file and one sample database accessed by it in WampServer. There shouldn't be any major issues, unless you are using some strange one-off non-standard stuff that works on XAMPP and does not work on WAMP. You will need to do the regular round of backup and testing for your specific projects in question.

btw, someone who comes along is going to find the question too broad and may downvote it. SO encourages questions that present the piece of code that has the problem and asks for a specific issue, not general suggestions on migration.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll update the question with more details.